# Remove newlines from a parameter passed to a macro

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I want to have a command that receives some text and prints it out in a certain style, etc. I also want to ensure that the printed line will not have forced linebreaks i.e. if someone does

```
\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph}
```

I want to print `first paragraph second paragraph` and make it follow the normal line breaking based on the line width

Answer (score 6):

within some local group set up by your macro define

```
\def\\{\relax\ifhmode\unskip\fi\space\ignorespaces}
```

so that `a\\b   a  \\  b` each  act like `a b` as `\\` will remove any space before itself, add one space and then ignore any following spaces.

David

Comment: Works like a charm, especially when within a custom class and defining a function where I don't have control over incoming argument data.

Answer (score 2):

A recursion to filter out `\\`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\mymacroaux#1\\\relax}
\long\def\mymacroaux#1\\#2\relax{%
  #1\ifx\relax#2\else\unskip\ \mymacroaux\ignorespaces#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph}X

\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph} X

\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph\\3rd paragraph }X

\mymacro{first paragraph 

second paragraph\\3rd paragraph 

Fourth para} X
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted a version that did not deplete the stack, then

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\mymacroaux#1\\\relax}
\long\def\mymacroaux#1\\#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\def\next{}%
  \else\unskip\ \def\next{\mymacroaux\ignorespaces#2\relax}%
  \fi%
  \next%
}
\begin{document}
\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph}X

\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph} X

\mymacro{first paragraph \\ second paragraph\\3rd paragraph }X

\mymacro{first paragraph 

second paragraph\\3rd paragraph 

Fourth para} X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also found this workaround which redefines `\\` to produce an empty string

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{ {\let \\ \empty #1} }
```

Comment: Well, this will disable ``\\`` forever (in the current group). Moreover you'll not be removing excess spaces.

Comment: @egreg sorry, forgot to add group