# How to apply title line breaks on the title page, but not in the page headlines?

Tags: line-breaking, titlesec, white-space, titling

I would like to have a macro which pass the book title both to the title page and to the page headlines. Unfortunately if I pass the title containing new line command (to break line on title page) then the line is broken also in page headline.

For resolving conflict between `titling` and `titlesec` packages I am using [@frabjous solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/titlesec-versus-titling-mangling-thetitle). Probably I have to combine it with some method of removing new line command, given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376246/remove-newlines-from-a-parameter-passed-to-a-macro). I don't know how to do this.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=11cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\fancyhead[LE]{\mythetitle}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythetitle}{#1}}

\author{Cookiemonster}
\title{Title\\consisting of \\ four \\lines}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\section{My section}
AAA
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

BTW: In accordance to the documentation of `titling` package (top of the page 5) after title page the page number should be 1, not 2. What I am doing wrong in this code?

Comment: `\fancyhead[LE]{\renewcommand\\{\space\ignorespaces}\mythetitle}`

Comment: The pagecounter of the following page is only set to 1 for a onesided document, for some reason, `titling` doesn't set it in a twoside document (well, even/odd detection wouldn't work correctly without an additional `\cleardoublepage`). So you have to do it yourself, just put `\setcounter{page}{1}` after `\end{titlingpage}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this will give two spaces if there is a space before `\\ `.

Comment: @Skillmon you shouldn't have a space before:-) but changing it to `\ifhmode\unskip\fi\space\ignorespace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\renewcommand\\{\unskip\space\ignorespaces}\mythetitle}
```

so that within the head `\\`  acts as a space, while ignoring space before and after so you do not get doubled spaces.

Comment: Good minimalistic solution!

Answer (score 2):

The following removes the `\\` from your title using `l3regex` (because there might be spaces before and after the `\\` which have to be normalised to one space in total, and doing this with a regular expression is pretty convenient).

Additionally I fixed the page numbering to start with 1, but to get correct odd/even page formatting one has to introduce a blank page after the title in that case (done so with `\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=11cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\fancyhead[LE]{\mythetitle}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\oldtitle\title
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \SXforrest_store_title:Nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s* \c{\\} \s* } { \  } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_gset_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \storemytitle \SXforrest_store_title:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{#1}\storemytitle\mythetitle{#1}}

\author{Cookiemonster}
\title{Title\\consisting of \\ four \\lines}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{My section}
AAA
\newpage
BBB
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]